# Why the fitted values are generated from the first data when running arima() in R?

Tags: r, arima

When we run arima() in R, for example,

y<-ts(InflationRate[,'Inflation'],start=c(2011,01),frequency=12)
model<-arima(y, order=c(12,0,0))
residuals(model)

And my results look like:
[image]

This is an ar(12) model. I am wondering why the residuals start from 2011/01, which is the same date as the first data in my original data? As there is not enough (12) lag terms for the inflation data from 2011/01 to 2011/12 to do regression and get the fitted value, I thought the residual list should be starting from 2012/01.

Could anyone tell me how estimation in function arima() works?

Answer (score 2):

From the help file for `stats::arima`

> The exact likelihood is computed via a state-space representation of
>   the ARIMA process, and the innovations and their variance found by a
>   Kalman filter. The initialization of the differenced ARMA process uses
>   stationarity and is based on Gardner et al (1980). For a differenced
>   process the non-stationary components are given a diffuse prior
>   (controlled by kappa). Observations which are still controlled by the
>   diffuse prior (determined by having a Kalman gain of at least 1e4) are
>   excluded from the likelihood calculations.

So it uses exact (not conditional) maximum likelihood estimation. The first few fitted values can be computed as expected values based on the past information. So the first fitted value is $E(y_1)$ which is the mean of the process since it is stationary, the second fitted value is $E(y_2 | y_1)$, etc.